# MVC Controller POST does not work with custom parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

**Answered! Solution at the bottom of the question **

Hi I'm starting to toy with MVC 4 and I've quickly hit a wall.
Note: I'm using Newtonsoft.JSON for all JSON related stuff.

I'm trying to POST a json to my controller that looks like this (in fiddler):

```
POST http://localhost:10187/api/Account/Login/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:10187
Content-Length: 63
ContentType: "application/json"

{
   "username" : "blahblah",
   "password" : "mypassw0rd"
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public PostLoginResponse Login(PostLoginModel model)
    {
        return new PostLoginResponse()
        {
            Status = model.Username,
            Token = model.Password
        };
    }
}
```

and here are the two models used:

```
public class PostLoginModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class PostLoginResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Now what seems to happen is that my controller doesn't seem to convert the JSON body sent in my request to a PostLoginRequest. If I check in my controller if (model == null) is always true.

What am I missing here? I've tried to read on Model Binding but could not get anything working. If I replace the return statement to use strings like the following:

```
return new PostLoginResponse()
{
    Status = "Hahaha",
    Token = "It WORKS!"
};
```

It works flawlessly.
Any pointer or help will help.

@Update:

Tried with:

```
[HttpPost]
public PostLoginResponse Post([FromBody]PostLoginModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's null");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's invalid");
    }

    return new PostLoginResponse()
    {
        Status = model.Username,
        Token = model.Password
    };
}
```

And I'm getting the same errors. It seems the model is null but it is valid.
I get the It's null but not the It's invalid. And tried with both "application/json" and application/json as contenttype with no success (same thing happens in both cases)

@Update 2:
Screw me... Thanks to haim770 for making me look at the content-type header.
It's Content-Type not ContentType!

Changing the header to Content-Type: application/json made everything work like a charm.

Thanks a bunch guys.

Comment: Is your 'Content-Type' header `"application/json"` or `application/json`?

Comment: By the way, im not good in json values income for controllers, but what if you try public PostLoginResponse Login(string username, string password)? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

First, try naming your action after the HTTP verb in play, i.e. `PostLogin` instead of `Login`. If that doesn't work or alternatively try adding `[FromBody]` to your action argument:

```
public PostLoginResponse Login([FromBody]PostLoginModel model)
```